How can I sync updated user permissions in a NextAuth session after an admin changes them, without requiring a re-login?
I'm working on a Next.js application with NextAuth, where user permissions are stored in the session along with other user data. Currently, the user permissions are retrieved at login and stored in the session, which works fine initially. However, if an admin updates a user's permissions from the admin dashboard, the changes are not reflected in the user's session unless they log out and log back in.
I’m considering two options:

Refetching the full user data on every request to ensure permissions are always up-to-date.
Checking permissions directly from the database with each request.

However, both options could introduce additional latency.
What would be the best approach to handle this situation and ensure that user permissions are updated in the session promptly when changed by an admin, without impacting performance?

If the requirement is instant updates, you have no other choice than to look up user in db on every request. I believe that accepting stale permissions for a period, like 15 minutes, is more normal. BR
